# Every few times, Slider values cannot be saved to UserDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I save the values set in Slider to UserDefaults.
By using onEditingChanged, I can detect when the editing is done and save the value to UserDefaults.
However, there are times when the value is not saved correctly.
Why is this?

The code is below.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SliderAndUserDefaults: View {

    @StateObject var textOptions: TextOptions = .makeUserOptions()
    private let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Slider(
                value: $textOptions.fontSize,
                in: 8...40,
                step: 1
            ) {
                Text("font size")
            } minimumValueLabel: {
                Text("8")
            } maximumValueLabel: {
                Text("40")
            } onEditingChanged: { editing in
                if !editing {
                    print(" save fontSize: \(textOptions.fontSize)")
                    userDefault.set(textOptions.fontSize, forKey: "fontSize")
                }
            }

            Slider(
                value: $textOptions.lineSpacing,
                in: 1...20,
                step: 1
            ) {
                Text("line spacing")
            } minimumValueLabel: {
                Text("1")
            } maximumValueLabel: {
                Text("20")
            } onEditingChanged: { editing in
                if !editing {
                    print(" save lineSpacing: \(textOptions.lineSpacing)")
                    userDefault.set(textOptions.lineSpacing, forKey: "lineSpacing")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class TextOptions: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fontSize: CGFloat
    @Published var lineSpacing: CGFloat

    static let defaultFontSize: CGFloat = 12
    static let defaultLineSpacing: CGFloat = 4

    init(fontSize: CGFloat, lineSpacing: CGFloat) {
        self.fontSize = fontSize
        self.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
    }

    static func makeUserOptions() -> TextOptions {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let savedFontSize: Int = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "fontSize")
        let savedLineSpacing: Int = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "lineSpacing")

        print(" savedFontSize: \(savedFontSize)")
        print(" savedLineSpacing: \(savedLineSpacing)")

        let fontSize: CGFloat = savedFontSize == 0
        ? defaultFontSize
        : CGFloat(savedFontSize)
        let lineSpacing: CGFloat = savedLineSpacing == 0
        ? defaultLineSpacing
        : CGFloat(savedLineSpacing)

        print(" fontSize: \(fontSize)")
        print(" lineSpacing: \(lineSpacing)")

        return .init(fontSize: fontSize, lineSpacing: lineSpacing)
    }
}
```

For example, if I set fontSize: 40.0, lineSpacing: 20.0, and then restart, I get
fontSize: 8.0, lineSpacing: 1.0 remains. It happens once every 2~3 times, not always.

```
// change slider value
 save fontSize: 40.0
 save lineSpacing: 20.0

// restart app
 savedFontSize: 8
 savedLineSpacing: 1
 fontSize: 8.0
 lineSpacing: 1.0
```

Device: iPhone 14 Pro Simulator

Comment: Use AppStorage it would likely be more liable.

Comment: In my experience there is a small time delay between writing something to user defaults and it being persisted. When debugging with Xcode if you kill or restart the app too quickly after making a change, the change will not have had time to be persisted. I find that going back to the Home Screen before restarting the app forces the user defaults to be saved. Perhaps you are seeing this, which explains the seemingly random behaviour?

Comment: Or try on a real device to see if this is an issue with the simulator